# F# type inference misses given information

Tags: f#, type-inference, type-annotation

If I declare this F# function:

```ml
let extractColumn col (grid : List<Map<string, string>>) =
    List.map (fun row -> row.[col]) grid
```

the compiler complains:

> error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints

Adding a type annotation for the lambda's `row` parameter fixes it:

```
let extractColumn col (grid : List<Map<string, string>>) =
    List.map (fun (row : Map<string, string>) -> row.[col]) grid
```

Why can't it get the type of `row` from the `extractColumn` function's `grid` parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F#'s type inference works from left to right and top to bottom.

Type of `grid` isn't available in the `List.map (fun row -> row.[col])` part.

Using pipe operator `|>`:

```
let extractColumn col (grid : Map<string, string> list) =
    grid |> List.map (fun row -> row.[col])
```

makes your example work as expected.